# Asp-page tag helper always redirect to the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

when i use asp-page it always redirect to the same page and when I replace it by href it work fine 
how i can make asp-page helper work ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please show me the page source when it is loaded form `asp-page` anchor tag and  `href` anchor tag

Comment: Page Source => Pages Folder

Comment: Can you show us your project structure? Where is the current view and where is the carDetails view?